# Can an SSAS Cube be used as a data source for a data warehouse/BI database?

Tags: ssis, ssas, msbi

I have a requirement to pull data from an existing 3rd-party SSAS cube into my current BI system.

Is there a best practice for how to do this? Can a cube be used as a source for another BI database? How do I import this data?

I'm open to suggestions of better alternatives if they exist.

Answer (score 0):

You can export data from a cube and load into any database you want.
However exporting data from cubes could be painful depending on the volume of data you would like to export.
You can write a c# program which access the cube with adomd and retrieve the results. 
Afterwards you can write to anywhere you would like.
If the volume is high, you probably need to make that c# program multithreaded.

Comment: You can also write a SQL query using OPENROWSET with an MDX query in it. You would have to test performance.